# C# Regex replace round brackets and contents at end of string

Tags: c#, regex

Been struggling for an hour to get this working.

Have string of following format:

"blabla(arbitrarycontent)sfsf (arbytrarycontent)"
and also
"blabla (arbytrarycontent)"

I need to ditch the "(arbitrarycontent)", including the brackets, if it occurs at the end of the string.

So the first example the result should be "blabla(arbitrarycontent)sfsf".
For the second it should be "blabla".

Have tried all sorts of Regex patterns like below but unsuccessful.

```
\(.*\)$
```

Using .NET 4.0

Thx for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply forbid the part between the parentheses to contain parentheses. That makes sure that you only match the last pair:

```
\([^()]*\)$
```

Comment: Thank you you are legend ! Saved my day